# Nginx configuration doesn't seem to enable http3

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, http3

Now that Nginx 1.25.1 support quic/http3 on the run, I try to enable it by following either their doc or few examples over the internet, but so far I couldn't get anything to work: it's always served over http1.1.

(I have no issue enabling http2, just for the record).

Here's my config file for a test vhost:

```
server {
    listen 443 quic;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    http3 on;

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|srt|swf|woff|woff2)$ {
        root /var/www/landings/mywebsite/site/;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8005/;
        root /var/www/landings/mywebsite/site/;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/headers.conf;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

I tried a few various steps, like with or without the http3 directive, with `add_header QUIC-Status $http3;`, and stuff that would regularly pop up in tutorials pages, but so far nothing did the trick.

TLSv1.3 is enabled.

The logs show nothing specific, and nginx configuration check is all clear.
Nginx version is 1.25.1 on debian bullseye.

If anyone has an idea of what I could have missed… Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some tries, I was able to make HTTP/3 to work by adding the following headers, according [this official nginx blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/binary-packages-for-preview-nginx-quic-http3-implementation/):

```
server {

    listen 443 quic;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    ...

    # Add Alt-Svc headers to negotiate HTTP/3
    add_header Alt-Svc  'h3=":$server_port"; ma=3600, h2=":$server_port"; ma=3600';
    add_header Alt-Svc  'h2=":$server_port"; ma=2592000; persist=1';
    add_header Alt-Svc  'h2=":$server_port"; ma=2592000;';

    ...

}
```

(you can replace `$server_port` by `443` if this is the port you're using for HTTPS)

It seems one can add those headers either in a specific vhost file in the `server` directive, or for all vhosts in the `nginx.conf` in the `http` directive. Maybe it didn't work for you since you put the header in the `location` directive.

By the way:

1. It seems the `http3 on` directive is not necessary, as it is already [enabled by default](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v3_module.html) (which is [not the case for the `http2 on` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html))
2. While we're at it, it might be also a good idea to enable the [QUIC 0-RTT connection resumption feature](https://blog.cloudflare.com/even-faster-connection-establishment-with-quic-0-rtt-resumption/):

```
server {
    ...

    # Enabling QUIC 0-RTT
    ssl_early_data on;

    ...
}
```

Same, it seems this can alternatively be added for all vhosts in the `http` directive in the global `nginx.conf` conf file.

Comment: Thanks! I had check this blog post, and tried everything suggested to no avail. Still trying…